# Cannot display alert once the user login inputs incorrect credentials PHP PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

index.php

This is the login form

```
<div class="modal-body">

            <form action="loginPDO.php" method="post">

            <?php  if(isset($message))  
            {  
                 echo '<label class="text-danger">'.$message.'</label>';  
            }   ?>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Username:</label>
                <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Enter Username" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">Password:</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Enter Password" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" name="login" id="login" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Register</button>
               
            </div>
            </form>

            
        </div>
```

loginPDO.php

```
<?php

include 'dbconnection.php';   

 if(isset($_POST["login"]))  
      {  
           if(empty($_POST["username"]) || empty($_POST["password"]))  
           {  
                $message = '<label>All fields are required</label>'; 
                header("location:index.php");
                
           }  
           else  
           {  
                $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username AND password = :password";  
                $statement = $conn->prepare($query);  
                $statement->execute(  
                     array(  
                          'username'     =>     $_POST["username"],  
                          'password'     =>     $_POST["password"]  
                     )  
                );  
                $count = $statement->rowCount();  
                if($count > 0)  
                {  
                     $_SESSION["username"] = $_POST["username"];  
                     header("location:dashboard.php");  
                }  
                else  
                {  
                     $message = '<label>Wrong Data</label>'; 
                     header("location:index.php");
                     
                }  
           }  
      }  
?>
```

Hi Guys, I want to know how to display the alert message once the user inputs incorrect credentials

For example, Imagine the user inputs wrong credentials once the user clicks the login button it automatically appears the alert message above Username.

[image]

Comment: Of course many ways to display an error message on login. 1) include login validation code in the index.php file and POST form back to index.php, 2) add a GET value to the `header("location:index.php?error=wrong+data")` then grab that in your index.php page and display it on the login form, 3) set a cookie or session variable before redirect to index.php indicating error, 4) send form data to server for login validation using XHR, then return result to page, without reload, and use javascript to display error.

Answer (score 0):

`$message` just exists in file `loginPDO.php` and ...

```php
$message = '<label>Wrong Data</label>'; 
header("location:index.php");
```

Is not sufficient to pass the `$message` variable to `index.php`.

As said in comments you can try

```php
// file loginPDO.php
$message = '<label>Wrong Data</label>'; 
header("location:index.php?error=" . urlencode("Wrong Data"));
```

```php
// file index.php
<?php  
$message = isset($_GET['error']) ? $_GET['error'] : null; // get the error from the url 
if(!empty($message)) {  
    echo '<label class="text-danger">'.$message.'</label>';  
} ?>
```

Comment: Hi I tried the code but the error is Notice: Undefined index: error

Comment: I've edited the answer (index.php) to fix it